# Atmel AVR XMEGA I2C/TWI max speed

Tags: avr, i2c, speed, xmega, twi

I'm planning a communication bus between one ATxmega256A3U and multiple ATxmega64A3s. The challenge is that I need to use as few wires as possible, so I would like to address the slaves without a separate slave select pin for each. I need to estimate the maximum speed of the bus, because I have to guess the maximum number of slaves per one master.

Fortunately, both support TWI, which is a I2C implementation, if I understand correctly.
[I2C defines multiple speed grades:](http://www.i2c-bus.org/speed/)

- standard mode: 100 kbit/s
- full speed: 400 kbit/s
- fast mode: 1 Mbit/s
- high speed: 3,2 Mbit/s

The XMEGA datasheet clearly states that the standard and full speed modes are supported.

According to [the AVR315 application note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2564-Using-the-TWI-Module-as-I2C-Master_ApplicationNote_AVR315.pdf):

> The Bite Rate Generator unit controls the period of SCL when operating in a Master mode. The SCL
>   period is controlled by settings in the TWI Bit Rate Register (TWBR) and the Prescaler bits in the TWI
>   Status Register (TWSR). Slave operation does not depend on Bit Rate or Prescaler settings, but the CPU
>   clock frequency in the Slave must be at least 16 times higher than the SCL frequency.

The XMEGAs will run at 32Mhz, so slave speed is maximized at 2Mbit/s and we can use following the formula to calculate the exact speed

> I2CSpeed = CPUClock / (16 + 2 * TWBR - 4^TWBR), where valid TWBR values are between 1 and 256

I think it might *theoretically* be possible to reach the fast mode, since 32/(16*1-4^1)=2.66Mbit > 1.0Mbit (speed of fast mode).
(Fast mode's protocol is backward compatible with full speed.)

Has anyone reached this speed with XMEGA's TWI in practice? Are there any other limitations which I didn't realize?

Comment: Theres always noise and distance how far away will the slaves be or is it negligible?

Comment: The master-slave distance will always be less then 10 inches/25 cms. Is the noise something I should worry about?